# Can't extract data using xpath

Tags: xpath

I can't extract the address out of the element I'm pasting below. It's the "br" tag which is putting a barrier for the data to get extracted.

```
<div class="secondary-attributes">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" data-hovercard-id="1" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" class="icon icon--18-info icon--size-18 icon--currentColor yloca-info">
    <svg class="icon_svg">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#18x18_info"></use>
    </svg>
</span>

                                <span class="neighborhood-str-list">
            Nob Hill        </span>

                <address>
        700 Bush St<br>San Francisco, CA 94108
    </address>



    <span class="offscreen">Phone number</span>
    <span class="biz-phone">
        (415) 391-5008
    </span>

            </div>
```

I tried `XPath` like :

```
//div[@class="secondary-attributes"]/@address
```

Comment: What did you try? What technology are you using?

Comment: Share your `XPath`, current and desired output

Comment: replace `<br>` with `</br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `//div[@class="secondary-attributes"]/@address` you're trying to get *attribute* `address` from `div` while you need to get *text content* of `address` *child element*:

```
//div[@class="secondary-attributes"]/address/text()
```

If you need to extract `"700 Bush St"` and `"San Francisco, CA 94108"` separately, you might need to specify index:

```
//div[@class="secondary-attributes"]/address/text()[1]
```

for `"700 Bush St"` or

```
//div[@class="secondary-attributes"]/address/text()[2]
```

for `"San Francisco, CA 94108"`

Comment: Thanks Andersson, it works perfectly. Gonna accept your answer in some moment.

Comment: It's awesome to have the rest without even asking. Thanks again, Andersson.